# Ich suche ein deutsches Buch wie das englische "Descriptionary" Buch

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german

Das englische Buch [Descriptionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0816079471) (sample [here](https://abiiid.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/a-thematic-dictionary-descriptionary.pdf)) ist ein Buch, das englische Wörter erklärt und in Kategorien unterteilt.

Ein Beispiel wäre "link" ist in der Kategorie "Internet" in der Kategorie "Computers" in der Kategorie "Electronics" mit Erklärung "a connection to another Web page or site".

Gibt es ein ähnliches Buch auf deutsch?

Answer (score 2):

Vielleicht kann dir ein Wörterbuch für Deutsch als Fremdsprache helfen.

Hier gibt es ein Beispiel von Amazon: [Visuelles Wörterbuch Deutsch als Fremdsprache: Wörter- und Arbeitsbuch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3831091161):

[image]

<sup>Auszug aus dem Inhaltsverzeichnis</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Ich kenne das Buch selbst (noch) nicht, aber bei der überschaubaren Zahl anderer Antworten ist es vielleicht einen Versuch wert:

[Franz Dornseiff: Der deutsche Wortschatz nach Sachgruppen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110179210)